# Mal/Iframe-AL in my site

Tags: iframe, malware, yandex

Yandex.ru block my site, because there are "Mal/Iframe-AL", I check all files for `iframe` and `document.write` ant nothing found dangerous, how it's possible to check files ?

Answer (score 0):

check your htaccess file for a redirect